# altair: mark_geoshape tooltips disabled when adding additional chart with selection

Tags: python, tooltip, altair

I have a GeoDataFrame, that I plot as a mark_geoshape-map (map_). The color and tooltip is based on a specific column ('Pkw-Dichte'). This works fine so far.

Then I added another chart (legend), which allows to filter the map by state ('bland'). Everything seems to work as well, but now the tooltip of the map is disabled. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Probably this issue is not only mark_geoshape related, as I experienced the same in combination with mark_boxplot tooltips. I guess has something to do with the selection.

```
bland_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['bland'])

map_ = alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape(
).encode(
    tooltip=['Pkw-Dichte'],
    color='Pkw-Dichte'
).properties(
    height=700,
    width=500
).transform_filter(
    bland_selection
)

legend = alt.Chart(source).mark_rect(
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('bland:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='State', orient='right')),
    color=alt.condition(bland_selection,
                    alt.value('gray'),
                    alt.value('lightgray')),  
    tooltip=['bland:N'],
).add_selection(
    bland_selection
)


map_ | legend
```

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

Here is a reproducible example including the solution, adding:

```
.add_selection(
    bland_selection
)
```

... to the map_-chart.

The example is not quit clean, as I didn't figure out how to bin the selection, however it shows the point and the solution of the problem:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

counties = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'counties')
source = data.unemployment.url


bland_selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['id'])


map_=alt.Chart(counties).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color='rate:Q',
    tooltip=['rate:Q']
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'id', ['rate'])
).project(
    type='albersUsa'
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).transform_filter(
    bland_selection
).add_selection(
    bland_selection
)



chart=alt.Chart(counties).mark_rect().encode(
    y= alt.Y("id:O", bin=True),
    color=alt.condition(bland_selection,
                    alt.value('gray'),
                    alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip=['rate:Q']
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'id', ['rate'])
).add_selection(
    bland_selection
)

map_ | chart
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem?

Comment: As I was working on a reproducible example, I realized that I just had to add ".add_selection(bland_selection)" to the map_-chart.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by the OP by adding `.add_selection(bland_selection)` to the map as per their comment.